# I want to get DOM value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get `div.plyr__progress` value but I'm not sure hot to solve that. I can't access `0` index.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__progress')); // [1]
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__progress')[0]); //undifined
```

`[1]`

```
HTMLCollection []
0
:
div.plyr__progress
length
:
1
__proto__
:
HTMLCollection
item
:
ƒ item()
length
:
(...)
namedItem
:
ƒ namedItem()
constructor
:
ƒ HTMLCollection()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
:
ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
:
"HTMLCollection"
get length
:
ƒ ()
__proto__
:
Object
```

`output`

[image]

Comment: [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns an element or `null`. It does **not** return an array or collection

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry. I fixed my question. I used `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: No you haven't. Your code still has `document.querySelector('.plyr__progress')[0]`. Just remove the `[0]`

Comment: I'm sorry Too. I fixed my question again. I used getElementsByClassName Too

Comment: CSS class names, when used in `getElementsByClassName` should not include a `.` prefix. The code you're showing here would not produce the output you claim to see. I suggest you just use `document.querySelector('.plyr__progress')` to get the first matching element

Comment: actuary. I didn't use `.` I fixed question.

Comment: How about you post your **actual** code

Comment: thank you for reply. current code is actual.

Comment: Why did it take you four revisions to post your actual code? Is the example output accurate at this time? Was it actually generated from the code in this question as it is right now?

Comment: yes it was. I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: Where in your document is your code? Is it in the `<head>` or `<body>` sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a **live** [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). This means that the collection will update automatically as elements matching its query are added or removed.

At the time you run

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__progress')
```

there are no matching elements. This is why your console shows on the first line...

> ▶ HTMLCollection[]

If there were matching elements, it would look more like

> ▶ HTMLCollection [div.plyr__progress]

Because there are no matches at this time, this code...

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__progress')[0]
```

results in *undefined*.

---

So at some point **after** your code executes, an element was added or an existing one is altered to have class `plyr__progress`. Since your console is able to reflect changes to objects, you can see the added elements by expanding the `HTMLCollection` result from your first query.

Comment: Your expectations were right.  I could get DOM which I wanted If I used set timer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

change `document.getElementsByClassName('.plyr__progress')`
to `document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__progress')`

Comment: actuary. I didn't use `.` I fixed question.